# How to save the state(context) of multiple functions in a program

Tags: c, linux, context-switch, setjmp

We are trying to switch between multiple functions in our C program after saving the state using `setjmp` and `longjmp` but for only one function we are able to save the context not for other two functions. What could be the possible solution to it. Please suggest if necessary changes are required in the code.
In the `o/p` the state of `fun1()` is saved successfully in `env1` and we are able to resume it back, but in case of `fun2()` and `fun3()` the state is not saved in the `env2`, `env3`.

Sample o/p:

```
   i=0,j=999
   i=1,j=998
   i=2,j=997
   i=3,j=996
   ch=a
   ch=b
   ch=c
   ch=d
   a=0
   a=-1
   a=-2
   a=-3
   i=4,j=995/*The previous value of i is preserved*/
   i=5,j=996
   i=6,j=994
   i=7,j=993
   ch=<garbagevalue> /*The previous value of ch is lost*/
   ch=<garbagevalue>
   ch=<garbagevalue>
   ch=<garbagevalue>
   a=<garbagevalue>  /*The previous value of ch is lost*/
   a=<garbagevalue>
   a=<garbagevalue>
   a=<garbagevalue>
   i=8,j=992
  and so on..
```

Code follows:

```c++
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include<setjmp.h>
#define INTERVAL 5000
void fun1();
void fun2();
void fun3();
void timer_handler(int );
struct itimerval it_val;
jmp_buf env1,env2,env3;
int count=0;
void timer_handler (int signum)
{

  if(count==0){
    count++;
    fun1();
  }
  if(count==1){
    count++;
    fun2();
    }

  if(count==2){
    count++;
    fun3();
  }


L1:   
  if(count==3){
    count++;
    siglongjmp(env1,7);
    }
  if(count==4){
     count++;
     siglongjmp(env2,7);
    }

  if(count==5){
    count++;
    siglongjmp(env3,7);
    }
  count=3;
  goto L1;
}

void fun1()
{

  struct sigaction sa;
  int i=0,j=999;
  /* Install timer_handler as the signal handler for SIGVTALRM. */
  memset (&sa, 0, sizeof (sa));
  sa.sa_flags=SA_NODEFER;
  sa.sa_handler = &timer_handler;

  /* Configure the timer to expire after 250 msec... */
  it_val.it_value.tv_sec = INTERVAL/1000;
  it_val.it_value.tv_usec = (INTERVAL*1000) % 1000000;   
  it_val.it_interval.tv_sec = INTERVAL/1000;;
  it_val.it_interval.tv_usec=(INTERVAL*1000) % 1000000;


  sigaction (SIGALRM, &sa, NULL);
  setitimer (ITIMER_REAL, &it_val, NULL);
  while (1) {
    while(sigsetjmp(env1,3)==0){
      sleep(1);
       printf("i=%d,j=%d\n",i,j);
      i++;
      j--;
    }
  }
}

void fun2()
{
  struct sigaction sa;
  char ch='a';
  /* Install timer_handler as the signal handler for SIGVTALRM. */
  memset (&sa, 0, sizeof (sa));
  sa.sa_handler = &timer_handler;
  sa.sa_flags=SA_NODEFER;
  sigaction (SIGALRM, &sa, NULL);

  /* Configure the timer to expire after 250 msec... */
  it_val.it_value.tv_sec = INTERVAL/1000;
  it_val.it_value.tv_usec = (INTERVAL*1000) % 1000000;   
  /* ... and every 250 msec after that. */
  it_val.it_interval.tv_sec = INTERVAL/1000;;
  it_val.it_interval.tv_usec=(INTERVAL*1000) % 1000000;
  /* Start a virtual timer. It counts down whenever this process is*/

  setitimer (ITIMER_REAL, &it_val, NULL);

  /* Do busy work. */
  while (1) {
    while(sigsetjmp(env2,2)==0) {
      sleep(1);
      printf("ch=%c\n",ch);
      if(ch=='z')
        ch='a';
      ch++;
    }
  }
}

void fun3()
{
  struct sigaction sa;
  int a=0;
  /* Install timer_handler as the signal handler for SIGVTALRM. */
  memset (&sa, 0, sizeof (sa));
  sa.sa_handler = &timer_handler;
  sa.sa_flags=SA_NODEFER;
  sigaction (SIGALRM, &sa, NULL);

  /* Configure the timer to expire after 250 msec... */
  it_val.it_value.tv_sec = INTERVAL/1000;
  it_val.it_value.tv_usec = (INTERVAL*1000) % 1000000;   
  /* ... and every 250 msec after that. */
  it_val.it_interval.tv_sec = INTERVAL/1000;;
  it_val.it_interval.tv_usec=(INTERVAL*1000) % 1000000;
  /* Start a virtual timer. It counts down whenever this process is*/

  setitimer (ITIMER_REAL, &it_val, NULL);

  /* Do busy work. */
  while (1){
    while(sigsetjmp(env3,1)==0){
      sleep(1);
      printf("a=%d\n",a);
      a--;
    }
  }
}

int main ()
{
  timer_handler(1);
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You seem to be trying to implement some kind of threading without managing your stacks. This will not work. Ignoring the fact that pretty much everything in your code is undefined behavior, let's see what's actually going on.

You first call `timer_handler()`. This calls `fun1`. This sets a real time timer that will call `timer_handler()`. Then `fun1` calls `setjmp` and sleeps. At this point your stack looks something like this:

```
timer_handler, fun1 (env1 points here), sleep
```

Now you get a `SIGALRM`. You execute `timer_handler`, this time `count` is 1, so you call `fun2`. It does more or less the same thing as `fun1` and your stack looks like this:

```
timer_handler, fun1 (&env1), sleep, timer_handler, fun2 (&env2), sleep
```

One more `SIGALRM`. Stack looks like this:

```
timer_handler, fun1(&env1), sleep, timer_handler, fun2 (&env2), sleep, timer_handler, fun3 (&env3), sleep
```

One more `SIGALRM`, this is where the fun happens. You `siglongjmp` to `env1`. At this point your stack looks like this:

```
timer_handler, fun1
```

That's it. There might be stuff on the stack for `fun2` and `fun3` that might even work when you `siglongjmp` to them, but those parts are completely invalid now that you've rewound the stack pointer back to `fun1`. The call to `printf` seals the deal. Even if there might have been surviving parts on the stack that you could longjmp to, printf will definitely overwrite those parts.

> Please suggest if necessary changes are required in the code.

The necessary changes are to delete the code, forget that `setjmp` and `longjmp` exist and never speak of this again. You can't do this. I've seen successful implementations of poor mans threads using `setjmp` and `longjmp`, but they also set up special stacks for the threads with `sigaltstack`, had proper locking and critical sections implemented and restricted the allowed functions calls to a very limited set of functions. Using `printf` when running such code is as far as you can get from having defined behavior. And all the successful implementations of this were of the "Look at this, isn't it horrible?" kind, not something anyone would ever use in real code.

Answer (score 1):

Good Grief !!

I see you added the `SA_NODEFER` following your earlier question on this piece of code.

Mr POSIX says:

> The interaction between setitimer() and alarm() or sleep() is unspecified.

That may be enough to stop this from working... but, frankly, it is so absolutely frightful that it does not deserve to work.

To fix this you need to take all the logic out of the signal action function.  Signals are very, very nasty "software interrupts" and need to be handled very carefully, preferably with gloves, eye protection and steady hands.  Unless this is homework for `setjmp` etc., I would treat those as even more nasty, and avoid touching them at all at all.